# Errors while doing vue add vuetify(vue3 preview)

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3

I tried to start a `vue3` project with `vuecli`, but when I add `vuetify`, errors occurred while everything is normal when used `vue2`. It says

> Error: You cannot call "get" on a collection with no paths. Instead,
> check the "length" property first to verify at least 1 path exists.

[image: errorpicture]

someone has the same problem, need some solution, thank you.

Comment: see if this helps you https://gitmemory.com/issue/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/140/671288792, and if it does add your answer so others can get benefits out it.

Comment: Dont be afraid of researching and find an answer and post it. You can do this

Answer (score 11):

In this link https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/
Vuetify says:

> The current version of Vuetify does not support Vue 3. Support for Vue 3 will come with the release of Vuetify v3. When creating a new project, please ensure you selected Vue 2 from the Vue CLI prompts, or that you are installing to an existing Vue 2 project.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to `main.js`. It would solve the problem

```
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    vuetify,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just choose **Vuetify 3** if you are using **Vue 3**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

vue3 is giving this error because vue3 is in beta version if you use vue2 you solve your problem. My error is solved by this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with the vue2 version as creating vue instance. I got the same error too and vue2 prevented the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to used 'Vue-3 + Vuetify' exclude TypeScript Later you can include when you finished initializing and added 'vue add vuetify'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Vue create

use vue version 2

after installation run vue add vuetify

error solve

Answer (score 0):

When prompted, Choose Vuetify 3 Preview (Vuetify 3)

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could add some details of how this would solve the OP's question.